# Retrieving french characters from xml to Java

Tags: java, xml, utf-8, xml-parsing, pdf-writer

We have a xml language file with French and English elements. French characters are coming with random text like é from xml to Java. I tried converting string to byte array with utf-8. These french elements i am using in PDF headers.I have downloaded ttf file, pdf table values are working fine but headers are not converted to normal text.

Please suggest.

Comment: é does not look like random text. What suggestions have you tried? if you've tried almost all you've likely already tried anything we come up with

Comment: There's nothing not "normal" about French (not "french") text. On the face it looks like your code, which you haven't shown us, is working correctly. What is the encoding of the XML (not "xml") file?

Comment: Its 'utf-8' encoding i am using for xml and Java string.